# Foreign Key in Django - second Form

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-keys, modelform

I have a second form that have to be filed after the first.
However I'm not able to save the relation between both models, unless I give the option for the person that have filing the forms chose the email for the first form.My idea is to give this information directly on the back end, but I cant do that.

My models are too big to post all here, so if any can help me with a generic idea I will be glad.

I'm using in both forms a ModelForm in Django.

my Models: 
                                           User 
                                         Person
                    Volunteer  -  Client - Staff

Than I have 3 types of volunteers: Admin; Program; Committee;
After I fill the Volunteer-Person-User model, I need to go to the next form for Volunteer Admin or Volunteer Program or Volunteer Committee;

because the user uses the email as a primary key also, thats the value when I create the foreign key from my admin program and the modelform give me the choices to the email. but on the database, only keeps the id for the reference.

my first view that's handling the first form:

```
def volunteer_form(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = VolunteerForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        saving = form.save(commit=False)
        saving.password = make_password(form.cleaned_data['password'])
        saving.save()
        item = saving.id
        if saving.person_volunteer_type == 'Program':
            return HttpResponse('<script language="JavaScript"> location.href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/volunteer_program?id=' + str(item) + '" </script>')

        elif saving.person_volunteer_type == 'Admin"]':
            return HttpResponse('<script language="JavaScript"> alert("You have sucessful created a new Volunteer"); location.href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/clock_in/" </script>')

        elif saving.person_volunteer_type == 'Committee':
            return HttpResponse('<script language="JavaScript"> alert("You have sucessful created a new Volunteer"); location.href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/clock_in/" </script>')

else:
    form = VolunteerForm()

return render(request, 'loginPortal/volunteer_form.html', {'form' : form})
```

the on handling the 2nd form:

```
def volunteer_program(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = VolunteerProgramForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        saving = form.save(commit=False)
        saving.pvolunteer_personid_id = form.cleaned_data.get('id_pvolunteer_personid_id')
        saving.save()
        return HttpResponse('<script language="JavaScript"> alert("You have sucessful created a new Volunteer"); location.href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/clock_in/" </script>')

elif request.method =='GET':
    item = request.GET['id']
    form = VolunteerProgramForm()

    return render(request, 'loginPortal/volunteer_program.html', {'form' : form , 'item' : item })

else:
    form = VolunteerProgramForm()

return render(request, 'loginPortal/volunteer_program.html', {'form' : form })
```

Comment: If your models are too big, please post a shorter example. It would make it easier to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, are you saying you need the `email` field to be filled out for the first form but that field is on the second form?

Comment: Can you just post the models with relevant fields only, and also the bit of the view that deals with the forms?

Comment: Can you edit your question with that information, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generic answer, asuming that your second model has a ForeignKey to the first model. Do this in your view's post:

1) Validate the first form, if it won't validate, return with errors.

2) Validate the second form, if it won't validate, return with errors.

3) If both validate, save the instance from the first form:

```
first_instance = first_form.save()
```

4) Save the instance from the second form without commiting changes to database:

```
second_instance = second_form.save(commit=False)
```

5) Update the foreign key on the second model instance:

```
second_instance.fk_to_first_model = first_instance
```

6) Save the second instance to database

```
second_instance.save()
```

7) Return success!

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm already saving the first form, and everything works perfectly, however, I don't know how to pass the second form with the relation. Like, I'm using modelForm and If i put the normal instance for the field that relate to the first form, will appeear an "option input" to chose the email referent to the user. My intention is do not give this option to the user and pass this value automatically.

Comment: In the second form, do not include the foreign key field in the form. You could do this whitelisting the other fields or blacklisting the foreign key (first option is better). This way, the second form won't handle at all the selection of the foreign key. That's precisely what you do when you save the second form with commit=False, otherwise it would raise an IntegrityError, and then you store the first instance on the ready-to-be-stored second model.

Comment: First, your second form must know which user was created without asking the user again. The only way to do it is passing it to the second view, so you either pass the plain email in the url, or encode it and pass it in the url. Then, in the second view, you can infer the user you need to supply to the foreign key by querying against the email that came as a parameter. Other way to do it would be storing the email in the session, and then querying the session in the second view.

Comment: That was exactly what I though and have try, however I wasn't able to save the data that I have retrieving...